# Upload multiple images using alamofire without using for loop in swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, image-uploading

I am working on uploading multiple images using for loop by alamofire networking, but I want to upload multiple images without using for loop. Is there any method or way to upload multiple images without for loops.

Comment: I think you need to go for Dispatch Group concept that will help you
https://www.raywenderlich.com/5371-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-2-2

Comment: multipart data request but your server should be ready to accept it

Comment: You can use multipart data and in that you can mention the multiple image data you need to send(again using fo loop), but your server also should be compatible to accept multipart images

Comment: but how could i use it without for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code from my work, You will need to import some required classes and change parameters based on your web-service parameters.

```
func uploadImage(url:String, parameters:Dictionary<String, Any>, images:[UIImage])  {
    let URL = url
    //print (URL, parameters)

    //show uploading
    SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: NSLocalizedString("Uploading Image", comment: "").loadigSuffix())
    SVProgressHUD.setDefaultMaskType(.none)
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        for image_ in images {
            if let imageData = self.serverCompatibleImageData(image: image_) {
                //print("final Image size = ", imageData)
                multipartFormData.append((imageData), withName: "userfile[]", fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
            }
        }

        for (key, value) in parameters {
            let val = String(describing: value)
            multipartFormData.append((val.data(using: .utf8))!, withName: key)
        }

    }, to: URL, method: .post, headers: ["Authorization" : "auth_token"],
       encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.response { [weak self] response in
                guard self != nil else {
                    debugPrint("Self does not have the authority here!")
                    return
                }

                var serializedData : Any? = nil
                var message = NSLocalizedString("Success", comment: "")+"!"//MUST BE CHANGED TO RELEVANT RESPONSES
                var success:Bool!

                //check content availability and produce serializable response
                do {
                    serializedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)
                    //debugPrint(message, "Response Dictionary:", serializedData ?? "Data could not be serialized", separator: "\n")
                    success = true
                }catch{
                    message = NSLocalizedString("Webservice Response error", comment: "")+"!"
                    let string = String.init(data: response.data!, encoding: .utf8) as String!
                    success = false

                    do {
                        if let s = string?.substring(from: (string?.index(of: "{")!)!) {
                            if let data = s.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                                serializedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)
                                debugPrint(message, "_:", serializedData ?? "Data could not be serialized", separator: "\n")
                            }
                        }
                    }catch{
                        debugPrint(message, error.localizedDescription, "Respone String:", string ?? "No respone value.", separator: "\n")
                    }
                }

                //call finised response in all cases
                self?.delegate?.uploaded?(succes: success, and: serializedData, message: message)
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            debugPrint("Error:\(encodingError)")
            //self.handleImageError()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: but how could i use it without for loop? so that when first image is busy to upload then second image wait until first image uploaded.

Comment: I add all images to form data (encoded) and then upload all of those all together. For loop here is used to merge all images to form data.

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
var list = [UIImage]()

    func uploadImages(){
        if list.isEmpty{
            return
        }
        uploadImage(otherData: [:], image: list.first!)
    }

    func uploadImage(otherData: [String : String], image: UIImage) {
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
            multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "file",fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
            for row in otherData{
                if !row.value.isEmpty{
                    multipartFormData.append(row.value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: row.key)
                }
            }
        },
                         to: "https://yourwebservice")
        { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                    print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                })
                upload.responseString {response in
                    self.list.removeFirst()
                    self.uploadImages()
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

You need an array of images declared at class level and call the uploadImages() function. this function will be responsible to initiate upload for all the images in the array. on successful response from server, I removed the first element and call the uploadImages() again. this process will continue until all the images aren't uploaded. however this process will be stopped in case of upload failure.. see failure case.